# Get only numbers after a certain character (#) with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
 #35+#36+#37+#38+#39+#40+#46+#47+#48+#49+#50+#51
```

How would I achieve getting only numbers after the `#`.

Also how can I get any numbers that have no `#` in front?

Comment: Regex in which language? Bash, Perl, Python? Try being more specific.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you tried/researched already.

Comment: It's in PHP and I've been playing with https://regexr.com/ with no success. Learnt about regex this week, planning on learning it this weekend. Its just I need this code today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match numbers preceded by `#` use `(?<=#)\d+` (positive lookbehind
for `#`, then a non-empty sequence of digits).

To match numbers not preceded by `#` use `(?<!\d|#)\d+` (negative lookbehind).
This time however the "forbidden" preceding char is either a `#` or a digit.

Of course, use both patterns with `g` (global) option.

If you want to process **all** numbers is a **single loop** and within this
loop detect, whether the number has a preceding `#`, you can use another
option, namely `(#?)(\d+)`.

This pattern contains 2 groups:

- optional `#` and
- a sequence of digits.

Then, processing each match, read the number from group 2 and check group 1,
whether it contains the `#`.